# ./Backup_date line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `done' ./Backup_Date.sh: line 20: `done'

Tags: linux, debian

> Write a script that takes a folder as arguments. Your script should compress the files in this folder into a zip file. Your script should:
>
> 1. Check the number of arguments?
> 2. Check that the file exists?
> 3. Create a Backup_Date.zip file?
> 4. Only files belonging to the user, who runs the script, will be compressed

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

dossier=$1

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] ; then
  echo "Err66: Pas de Parametres"
  exit 10
fi

DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
nomlog="Backup-$DATE.log"
nomFichier="Backup-$DATE.zip"
dossierCourant=`pwd`
ListeFichiers=$(ls -a $dossierCourant)

if [[ ! -d $dossier ]] ; then
  echo "Dossier n'existe pas.">> $nomlog
else
  zip $nomFichier -C $dossier/$ListeFichiers >> $nomlog
fi

done
```

When run, I had :

```
./Backup_Date.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

./Backup_Date.sh: line 20: `done'
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't have `done` without a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: You should quote your variables. The script won't work if the directory has spaces in the name.

Comment: Just get rid of the `done` line at the end, it's not needed.